# Запрет переопределения стилей CSS

Tags: gwt, javascript, java, css

У меня есть два файла со стилями, назовем их 1.css и 2.css. С начала загружается 1.css, потом - 2.css. В 1.сss находятся продвинутые стили, в 2.css - базовые. Как сделать так, чтоб продвинутые стили не заменялись базовыми (смотри порядок загрузки)?

PS Базовые стили находятся в сгенерированном коде. Т.е. у меня такой код страницы

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="patch/to.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

    <div id="content" align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

2.css вызывается из to.nocache.js. Может можно разместить ссылку на 1.css так, чтоб они загружались после 2.сss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда-то решил проблему так:

1. Компилируем со стандартными стилями
2. Убираем зависимость от стандартных стилей
3. Копируем папку gwt со всем содержимым в папку war (в эклипсе).
4. Вставляем ссылку на стандартные стили перед пользовательской.
5. Собираем заново.

PS Стандартные стили добавляются за счет добавления в appName.xml такой записи

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
```

Comment: Кул хак :)

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идет об отдельных стилях классов.

1.css

```
.some_class{
    background: red !important;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

2.css

```
.some_class{
    background: green;
    border: 1px solid brown;
}
```

У элемента .some_class фон останется красным.